# How do I call getString() inside the onBindViewHolder() method of a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

## Context

I am creating a RecyclerAdapter to display the forecast info on a certain day.  My RecyclerView contains multiple days, each of which is modified with the onBindViewHolder.

The layout of each day has 3 text views.  The first one contains a string that is the summary.  The second one contains a string with a double as a positional argument which represents the low temperature.  The third is identical to the second, but represents the high temperature.

Below is the code of my onBindViewHolder method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DailyForecastAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    Datum datum = forecast.get(i);

    TextView summary = viewHolder.summaryTextView;
    TextView tempHigh = viewHolder.tempHighTextView;
    TextView tempLow = viewHolder.tempLowTextView;

    summary.setText(datum.getSummary());
    tempHigh.setText(datum.getTemperatureHigh());
    tempLow.setText(datum.getTemperatureLow());
}
```

## Issue

Since high and low temperatures are **doubles**, I need to format the string accordingly, lest I overwrite the string with just a double value. Here are the string resources for high temperature and low temperature:

```
<string name="temperature_high">High of %1$.2f</string>
<string name="temperature_low">Low of %1$.2f</string>
```

**Outside of the RecyclerAdapter class I know how to do this,** below is an example of how I format a string inside a Fragment:

```
 String moddedString = String.format(getString(R.string.temperature), temp);
 ((TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.temperatureDisplay)).setText(moddedString);
```

However, **I don't have access to the `getString()` function inside the RecyclerAdapter**, so I cannot format the string appropriately to insert the temperature I need without completely overriding the String with a double.

## Question

How do I use `getString()` inside the `onBindViewHolder()` method?

Comment: Side note. There is [getString(int, Object...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)) method in Context class. So you can use `getString(R.string.temperature, temp)` instead of `String.format(getString(R.string.temperature), temp)`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> How do I use getString() inside the onBindViewHolder() method?

Every `ViewHolder` instance has an `itemView` field, which is an instance of `View`. Every `View` instance has a `getContext()` method; you can use this to access resources.

```
String text = viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

Comment: This answer is better since it stands alone, and there are no extra inferences needed to make it work. Also, I didn't have to expose context outside the local scope of a method, as I commented on @Ramesh's answer.

Comment: best answer to access context in an adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can you get string resource using context.

```
  context.getString(R.string.temperature)
```

Comment: What I did was I made context an instance variable inside my recycler adapter and then assigned it inside the `onCreateViewHolder()` method.  This indirectly helped.

Comment: There's no need to save a direct reference to `Context`; you can access the `ViewHolder`'s context on-demand. Of course, there's nothing really _wrong_ with doing this either.

Answer (score 1):

```
//1. Get context from adapter constructor:
public YourRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) 


//2. As @Ben P.said, get context from item view:
Context context = viewHolder.itemView.getContext();


//3. I think the adapter only binds the data to the view 
//and doesn’t care about the logic, so maybe you can 
//prepare the data before passing it to the adapter
CustomData {
    private String temperature;
    public String getTemperature() {
          return temperature;
    }
}
    
//Then pass the data to adapter by construtor:
YourRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new YourRecyclerViewAdapter(data);

//Or update data by adapter functions:
adapter.updateData(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a local copy of Context with the constructor of your RecyclerViewAdapter class:

```
public class YourRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private Context context;


    public YourRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String string = context.getString(R.string.your_string);
    }
```